# Go to the next record in the current view matching criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I don't often use Access, but I find myself working on a database where I have a command button with the following code:

```
Private Sub btnNextEmpty_Click()
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[new_org_id] IS NULL"
End Sub
```

This works... sort of. It does advance to the next empty record, but only if the user has worked all of the records in sequence. If the user needs to skip a record for some reason on continue, it always jumps back to that first one they skipped.

I need this code to be aware of the record position in the current view, and jump to the next record that comes *after* that position.

How can I do this?

Comment: `FindNext` begins searching from the current record. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194099.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy fix is using `.FindNext` instead of `.FindFirst`:

```
Me.Recordset.FindNext "[new_org_id] IS NULL"
```

A more advanced/customizable solution might be the following:

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordSetClone 'Open a clone
rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark 'Navigate to the current record
rs.FindNext "[new_org_id] IS NULL"
If rs.NoMatch Then
   'No record matching that criterium
Else
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark 'Move to the found record
End If
```

Comment: I hoped it'd be something that simple. Thanks. The lack of a quick, reliable, intellisense-like reference in the vba ide is killing me :/